# microRNA analysis statistical methodology review

Tags: survival, methodology, microarray

I am doing a review of statistical methodology used for microRNA data obtained from Affymetrix platform. I have data from 178 patients and their prognosis information as well as recurrence of disease and survival outcome (dead/alive).

I learnt that I can treat recurrence rate to separate patients into two groups (recurrence 1 case and recurrence 0 control).

Can you please give me a review of statistical methodologies used for such analysis? The first aim is to find a prognostic model i.e. correlations between microRNA and clinical outcomes and then validate it on other datasets.

Thanks.